# i want to upper first letter of words in django template

Tags: html, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this string

```
End of our days
```

I render this with:

```
  <td>{{ book.title|lower | capfirst }}</td>
```

but I want convert this to:

```
End Of Our Days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [**`|title`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#title):

```
<td>{{ book.title|title }}</td>
```